# Concatenate Gremlin GraphTraversal result with string

Tags: gremlin

In this very simple example I am trying to add a new vertex which should be labeled like an existing vertex but with some prefix attached:

```
g.V(1).addV('prefix_' + label()).valueMap(true)
```

What am I missing here? It's clearly not a String, but how would I serialize that?

```
gremlin> g.V(1).label()
==>Person

gremlin> g.V(1).constant(label())
==>[LabelStep]
```

Comment: You might want to edit the title to be something like "Concatenate strings in a Gremlin traversal". The title as it stands is confusing as it has another meaning that implies converting a whole traversal to its string form. Rather than just make the edit I thought you might like to do it. I answered your question below. Best of luck with Gremlin.

Comment: Thank you, that title is changed now. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gremlin today does not provide a built in string concatenation function. It would be nice if it did. That means your best alternative today is to use an in line closure/lambda. Here is an example using TinkerGraph and the air-routes graph.

```
gremlin> g.V(3).map {"prefix_" + it.get().label}.as('a').addV(select('a'))
==>v[60867]
gremlin> g.V(60867).label()
==>prefix_airport
```

Note that not all graph databases allow closures so this cannot be assumed to work universally on any TinkerPop enabled Graph DB backend.

Comment: Works for me (Bitsy + Gremlin v3.4.6)